# Call parent function inside callback function with same argument in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, callback

I have the bellow function

```
const generate_data = require('./helpers/generate_train_data');
const permutate_data = require('./helpers/permutate_data');

var COMPANY = 'test-company';
var INVOICES = ['invoice2.pdf','invoice4.pdf','invoice5.pdf'];

generate_data.generate_data(COMPANY, INVOICES,(check)=>{
    if(check){
        console.log('Success, training data created!');
    }
    else{
        //Call generate_data.generate_date again with SAME INPUT 
    }
});
```

Basically i am waiting for a return falue of the generate_date module, and if that value if true i just just a simple printout, but if that value is false i need to call again the same function

```
generate_data.generate_data(COMPANY, INVOICES, (AND HERE THE SAME CALLBACK...)
```

I tried using generate_data.generate_data.call(arguments.callee.caller),  but i get undefined value fo the arguments.callee.caller..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this by storing callback in separate function, so you reference it inside

```
const customCallback = (check) => {
    if (check) {
        console.log('Success, training data created!');
    } else {
        //Call generate_data.generate_date again with SAME INPUT 
        generate_data.generate_data(COMPANY, INVOICES, customCallback);
    }
}

generate_data.generate_data(COMPANY, INVOICES, customCallback);
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't even think about separating it, it troubled me badly today... Cheers.

Comment: @KristijanStefanoski Glad to help. Also do not forget to mark an answer as correct if it solved your probem)